# Google charts data type mismatch while dynamic row adding

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-visualization

.. so I'm trying to add data to create a Google Chart via loop & addRow(), like this:

```
   var splicedData = data.split(","); 
   //the data var is a string with several dates in this format (string): 
   // "day/month/year | hour:minutes:seconds", separated by commas.

   for(i = 0; i<splicedData.length-1; i++){

    dSplicedData = splicedData[i].split("|"); //split date and hour         
    ddSplicedData = dSplicedData[1].split(":"); // split hh, mm, ss
    dddSplicedData = dSplicedData[0].split("/"); //split dd, mm, yy

    chartData.addRow([

        [new Date ( parseInt(dddSplicedData[2]), //year
                parseInt(dddSplicedData[1]), //month
                parseInt(dddSplicedData[0]))], //day    
        [parseInt(ddSplicedData[0]), parseInt(ddSplicedData[1]), 0]
    ]);
   };
```

The index 0 of addRow() needs a 'datetime/date' datatype , the index 1 needs a 'timeofday'. As far as I understood it, both types are mapped in JS by the Date() method. In conclusion, looking at the API indications I think I've done it right, but I get this error:

"**Error: Type mismatch. Value *Wed Jul 20 2016 08:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)* does not match type datetime in column index 0**",

which is very weird, since the value matches the datatype and it's generated by the Date() method.

Furthermore, I've tried with a Google example, inserting random date manually (not looping a variable value; new Date(2000, 8, 5)), reference [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes), and it does not accept it either.

Comment: can you post a [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net) so that it would be easy to debug.

Comment: @Himanshu sure: https://jsfiddle.net/wfuhtevv/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dzmhtoau/)

You just need to remove the `[]` symbol around the date.

**HTML**

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**JS**

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  var dSplicedData = new Array();
  var ddSplicedData = new Array();
  chartData.addColumn('datetime', 'Día');
  chartData.addColumn('timeofday', 'Hora de entrada');
  /*    
      jQuery.extend({
          getValues: function(url) {
              var result = null;
              $.ajax({
                  url: url,
                  type: 'get',
                  dataType: 'html',
                  async: false,
                  success: function(data) {
                      result = data;
                  }
              });
            return result;
          }
      });

      data = $.getValues("getData.php"); */
  data = "19/6/2016 | 11:36:18,19/6/2016 | 11:36:44,20/6/2016 | 9:3:32";





  var splicedData = data.split(",");



  for (i = 0; i < splicedData.length - 1; i++) {

    dSplicedData = splicedData[i].split("|"); //data formatted, splitted

    ddSplicedData = dSplicedData[1].split(":"); // split hour
    dddSplicedData = dSplicedData[0].split("/"); //split date

    chartData.addRow([

      new Date(parseInt(dddSplicedData[2]),
        parseInt(dddSplicedData[1]),
        parseInt(dddSplicedData[0]))

      ,

      [parseInt(ddSplicedData[0]), parseInt(ddSplicedData[1]), 0]


    ]);


  };

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'foo',
      subtitle: 'bar'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));


  chart.draw(chartData, options);
};
```